# Get Hash from OS X-Encrypted USB Drive?

Tags: encryption, hash

I have a personal USB that was encrypted using Disk Utility on OS X 10.11 El Capitan using AES-256 encryption. I no longer have the password, but I have a list of likely prefixes that were used, suffixed by a number that I've forgotten. Brute force typing would still take too long.

I'm looking for a way to extract the hash used for the password, so that I could use a tool to iterate over the range of possibilities.

If the hash cannot be extracted, are there any tools that can automate the password entry?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to get a hash, but I did write a script that brute forces encrypted HFS+ drives. It uses Crunch for dynamic wordlist generation and GNU Parallel for multithreading. If you have a good idea of what the password is, you may have a shot with the tool. If not, it will take a billion years or more to crack. I have the tool hosted out on [Github](https://github.com/EvanWieland/brute).

Comment: Thanks for this! I still have that USB and this seems to be what I was after. I will give this a shot.